# How extract lines from a messy background

Tags: c++, opencv, edges

Given the next canny edge result image:

[image]

I'm trying to extract the selected lines:

[image]

I did try several methods without success. For ex. I tried morphological operations but didn't work well because some times the lines are in angle or they are not completely vertical or horizontal...

I wonder if there's a method or if it is possible to extract them properly.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the original image before canny?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the longest lines try with finding [contou](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)r and filter by its length.

You will get only the long connected lines irrespective of angle.

if you want that to match with line 
then try [houghlines](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. 
post some code .. so that more ppl will answer. .